# Is it possible to get values with tags from XML file using SAX parser?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I parse the large XML and i use SAX parser for it. I understand how to take values between XML tags. But i need to take all the values ​​ideally with the tags and save them to the string. Is this possible please?

**My parsing class:**

```
    public class EUServiceHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private StringBuilder currentValue = new StringBuilder();
        private SanctionedPerson PERSON;
        private List<SanctionedPerson> PERSONS = new ArrayList();
    
        private String MASTER_ELEMENT = "";
    
    
        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
            currentValue.setLength(0);
            switch (qName) {
                //create person
                case "sanctionEntity":
                    PERSON = new SanctionedPerson();
                    PERSON.setSource(EUSL);
                    PERSON.setId(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("logicalId")));
                    break;
                case "nameAlias":
                    // first name
                    if (PERSON.getFirst_name() == null || PERSON.getFirst_name() == "") {
                        if (attributes.getValue("firstName") != null || attributes.getValue("firstName") != "") {
                            PERSON.setFirst_name(attributes.getValue("firstName"));
                        }
                    }
                    // third name
                    if (PERSON.getThird_name() == null || PERSON.getThird_name() == "") {
                        if (attributes.getValue("middleName") != null || attributes.getValue("middleName") != "") {
                            PERSON.setThird_name(attributes.getValue("middleName"));
                        }
    
                    }
                    // last name
                    if (PERSON.getLast_name() == null || PERSON.getLast_name() == "") {
                        if (attributes.getValue("lastName") != null || attributes.getValue("lastName") != "") {
                            PERSON.setLast_name(attributes.getValue("lastName"));
                        }
                    }
                    // whole name
                    if (PERSON.getWholeName() == null || PERSON.getWholeName() == "") {
                        if (attributes.getValue("wholeName") != null || attributes.getValue("wholeName") != "") {
                            PERSON.setWholeName(attributes.getValue("wholeName"));
                        }
                        // function
                        PERSON.setDesignation(attributes.getValue("function"));
                    }        
                   
                    // nationality
                case "citizenship":
                    PERSON.setNationality(attributes.getValue("countryDescription"));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
            switch (qName) {
                //add to List
                case "sanctionEntity":
                    PERSONS.add(PERSON);
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            currentValue.append(ch, start, length);
        }
    
        public List<SanctionedPerson> getSanctionedPersons() {
            return PERSONS;
        }
}
```

**XML:**

```xml
<export generationDate="2022-04-25T11:10:26.382+02:00" globalFileId="139948">
  <sanctionEntity designationDetails="" unitedNationId="" euReferenceNumber="EU.27.28" logicalId="13">
    <remark>UNSC RESOLUTION 1483</remark>
    <regulation regulationType="regulation" organisationType="commission" publicationDate="2003-07-08" entryIntoForceDate="2003-07-07" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" programme="IRQ" logicalId="348">
      <publicationUrl>
        http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF
      </publicationUrl>
    </regulation>
    <subjectType code="person" classificationCode="P" />
    <nameAlias firstName="" middleName="" lastName="" wholeName="Abou Ali" function="" title="" nameLanguage="FR" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="380">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ  L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ  /LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </nameAlias>
    <nameAlias firstName="" middleName="" lastName="" wholeName="Abu Ali" function="" title="" nameLanguage="" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="19">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ  L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ  /LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </nameAlias>
    <nameAlias firstName="Saddam" middleName="" lastName="Hussein Al-Tikriti" wholeName="Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti" function="" gender="M" title="" nameLanguage="" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="17">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </nameAlias>
    <citizenship region="" countryIso2Code="IQ" countryDescription="IRAQ" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="1">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </citizenship>
    <birthdate circa="false" calendarType="GREGORIAN" city="al-Awja, near Tikrit" zipCode="" birthdate="1937-04-28" dayOfMonth="28" monthOfYear="4" year="1937" region="" place="" countryIso2Code="IQ" countryDescription="IRAQ" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="14">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </birthdate>
  </sanctionEntity>
  <sanctionEntity designationDetails="" unitedNationId="" euReferenceNumber="EU.39.56" logicalId="20">
    <remark>Saddam's second son</remark>
    <regulation regulationType="regulation" organisationType="commission" publicationDate="2003-07-08" entryIntoForceDate="2003-07-07" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" programme="IRQ" logicalId="348">
      <publicationUrl>
        http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF
      </publicationUrl>
    </regulation>
    <subjectType code="person" classificationCode="P" />
    <nameAlias firstName="Qusay" middleName="Saddam" lastName="Hussein Al-Tikriti" wholeName="Qusay Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti" function="Oversaw Special Republican Guard, Special Security Organisation, and Republican Guard" gender="M" title="" nameLanguage=""
      strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="26">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </nameAlias>
    <nameAlias firstName="Qoussaï" middleName="Saddam" lastName="Hussein Al-Tikriti" wholeName="Qoussaï Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti" function="" title="" nameLanguage="FR" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="381">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </nameAlias>
    <citizenship region="" countryIso2Code="IQ" countryDescription="IRAQ" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="2">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </citizenship>
    <birthdate circa="false" calendarType="GREGORIAN" city="Baghdad" zipCode="" year="1965" region="" place="" countryIso2Code="00" countryDescription="UNKNOWN" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="19">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </birthdate>
    <birthdate circa="false" calendarType="GREGORIAN" city="Baghdad" zipCode="" year="1966" region="" place="" countryIso2Code="00" countryDescription="UNKNOWN" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="20">
      <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF" />
    </birthdate>
  </sanctionEntity>
  . . . . . . . . . . .
</export>
```

This works but i also need to have a full record of each person from the beginning of the tag  to the end of the tag  like this :

```
String allXML= "<sanctionEntity designationDetails=\"\" unitedNationId=\"\" euReferenceNumber=\"EU.27.28\" logicalId=\"13\">\n" +
            "    <remark>UNSC RESOLUTION 1483</remark>\n" +
            "    <regulation regulationType=\"regulation\" organisationType=\"commission\" publicationDate=\"2003-07-08\" entryIntoForceDate=\"2003-07-07\" numberTitle=\"1210/2003 (OJ L169)\" programme=\"IRQ\" logicalId=\"348\">\n" +
            "      <publicationUrl>\n" +
            "        http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF\n" +
            "      </publicationUrl>\n" +
            "    </regulation>\n" +
            "    <subjectType code=\"person\" classificationCode=\"P\" />\n" +
            "    <nameAlias firstName=\"\" middleName=\"\" lastName=\"\" wholeName=\"Abou Ali\" function=\"\" title=\"\" nameLanguage=\"FR\" strong=\"true\" regulationLanguage=\"en\" logicalId=\"380\">\n" +
            "      <regulationSummary regulationType=\"regulation\" publicationDate=\"2003-07-08\" numberTitle=\"1210/2003 (OJ  L169)\" publicationUrl=\"http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ  /LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF\" />\n" +
            "    </nameAlias>\n" +
            "    <nameAlias firstName=\"\" middleName=\"\" lastName=\"\" wholeName=\"Abu Ali\" function=\"\" title=\"\" nameLanguage=\"\" strong=\"true\" regulationLanguage=\"en\" logicalId=\"19\">\n" +
            "      <regulationSummary regulationType=\"regulation\" publicationDate=\"2003-07-08\" numberTitle=\"1210/2003 (OJ  L169)\" publicationUrl=\"http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ  /LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF\" />\n" +
            "    </nameAlias>\n" +
            "    <nameAlias firstName=\"Saddam\" middleName=\"\" lastName=\"Hussein Al-Tikriti\" wholeName=\"Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti\" function=\"\" gender=\"M\" title=\"\" nameLanguage=\"\" strong=\"true\" regulationLanguage=\"en\" logicalId=\"17\">\n" +
            "      <regulationSummary regulationType=\"regulation\" publicationDate=\"2003-07-08\" numberTitle=\"1210/2003 (OJ L169)\" publicationUrl=\"http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF\" />\n" +
            "    </nameAlias>\n" +
            "    <citizenship region=\"\" countryIso2Code=\"IQ\" countryDescription=\"IRAQ\" regulationLanguage=\"en\" logicalId=\"1\">\n" +
            "      <regulationSummary regulationType=\"regulation\" publicationDate=\"2003-07-08\" numberTitle=\"1210/2003 (OJ L169)\" publicationUrl=\"http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF\" />\n" +
            "    </citizenship>\n" +
            "    <birthdate circa=\"false\" calendarType=\"GREGORIAN\" city=\"al-Awja, near Tikrit\" zipCode=\"\" birthdate=\"1937-04-28\" dayOfMonth=\"28\" monthOfYear=\"4\" year=\"1937\" region=\"\" place=\"\" countryIso2Code=\"IQ\" countryDescription=\"IRAQ\" regulationLanguage=\"en\" logicalId=\"14\">\n" +
            "      <regulationSummary regulationType=\"regulation\" publicationDate=\"2003-07-08\" numberTitle=\"1210/2003 (OJ L169)\" publicationUrl=\"http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF\" />\n" +
            "    </birthdate>\n" +
            "  </sanctionEntity>";
```

Is it possible to get all values ​​into a string using SAX parser as i wrote above?
Thanx in advance for all answers.

Comment: I think you would need to use a different approach than pure SAX, perhaps XQuery or XQuery or XSLT with streaming are better option to "materialize" each `sanctionEntity` element and get both the individual data as well as the serialization as a string.

Comment: Maintain your own element queue. Flag your own boolean `doCollect` as true starting with `<sanctionEntity>` in `startELement` and basically coilect all elements until `endElement`. Then the cycle starts again